# using AD to authenticate to different domains

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication

So we have been using the same login gode to connect to various domains in asp.net, with and without MVC. The code works.

We have a new server, first one to run server 2008 r2, set up with a directory structure similar to one of the ones that has been working.

Using forms authentication, I set up in the web.config

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://10.1.XXX.XXX"/>
```

and

```
 <!--<authentication mode="Windows" />-->
    <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider" >
      <providers >
        <add name="MyADMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
             connectionUsername="XXXX\Brown.Eric"
             connectionPassword="XXXX"
             connectionProtection="None"
             />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

It connects to build the membership provider just fine, but when I tryto use the exact same username and password to login on the forms login page (the stock asp.net stuff) it fails to login.

same user, same password that's being used to connect with the membership provider.

If I change the password in the web.config, I get an error that it's incorrect, so I know that the membership provider is getting connected with those credentials.

What I can't figure out is why can't I use the same credentials to login?

I've checked:
The user is not locked.
the user is not set to change password on next logon.
The user is not expired.

Any help or hints are apprecaited.

Thanks,

Cal-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, had indavertantly removed the use SAM Account setting from the above
config, and it was wanting me to use userPrincipalName instead.

Switched it back to sam and all worked as expected.

Cal-

Comment: I'm having the same issue but can't resolve it, could you perhaps update your OP with the correct membership definition?

Comment: Add  
attributeMapUsername="SAMAccountName" before connection protection = none